# problem showing boot list for dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 as dual boot.
**Note:** My bios is UEFI

1. Get 100 giga empty.
2. Download ubuntu.
3. Download rufus and burn ubuntu on it.
4. Restart and open bios.
5. Install ubuntu and it is successfully installed.

The problem is when I restart my laptop. It is directly opening windows and not showing me the list of operating systems.

Tried these solutions and failed:

1. Disable Secure boot.
2. Restoring bios settings.
3. From advanced system settings - (make time to display 30 seconds).
4. Downlaod easybcd (it doesn't work for uefi).
5. cmd commands (Access denied).

Can I have solutions to use Ubuntu?

Comment: We need more details of your configuration. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Try changing the boot order is you biso settings to the ubuntu partition

Comment: Some setups wipe EFI variables when Windows is booted into.

Answer (score 0):

When you install Ubuntu not using the .exe file in the  installation media (like booting directly from the media, like what you did) windows boot manager is likely not to recognize your Ubuntu installation. (Windows is totally unaware of Ubuntu's existence)
What you must do is to set the boot order in the BIOS settings in a way that your PC boots from the Ubuntu partition (or more specifically boot into GRUB). GRUB is Ubuntu's boot manager, which is totally fine with Windows and many other different OSs.
[This is how you can change the boot order in BIOS](https://www.lifewire.com/change-the-boot-order-in-bios-2624528)
[This is how you can set Windows as the default option of GRUB](https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/) so you don't have to choose Windows every time.

Comment: I didn't find any exe in any installation media of Ubuntu, and a lot of concepts here are for DOS BIOS instead of UEFI. the latter uses bootloader programs (/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi) in the EFI system partition instead of boot partitions.